# Olympic weight lifting bar, plate location affect

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, mass

I apologize in advance for the rudimentary nature of my question.

> *A perfectly balanced weight lifting bar is loaded with three weight plates on each side. The three plates are 25kg, 10kg and 5kg. On the left side of the bar the 25kg plate is innermost, then the 10kg plate, then the 5kg plate. On the right side of the bar the 10kg is innermost, then the 25kg plate, then the 5kg plate.*

I say the center of gravity will no longer be in the center of the bar but shift toward the right side since the 25kg plate on the right side has moved farther from the center of the bar.  My two friends say the center of gravity will remain dead center on the bar.

Answer (score 3):

The centre of gravity is the point at which all the [moments of force](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_%28physics%29) cancel out.

[image: Bar 1]

The moment is just the force times the distance from the pivot point. So on the left side the total moment is:

$$ T_{left} = 25gd_{25} + 10gd_{10} = 5gd_5 $$

where $d_25$ is the distance to the 25kg weight and so on. The constant $g$ is the gravitational acceleration: you can ignore this, it's just there to convert the mass to a force. Likewise on the right side we have:

$$ T_{right} = 25gd'_{25} + 10gd'_{10} = 5gd'_5 $$

With the weights arranged symmetrically we have $d_{25} = d'_{25}$, $d_{10} = d'_{10}$ and $d_{5} = d'_{5}$ so $T_{left} = T_{right}$ and the bar balances.

Now let's rearrange the weights as you describe:

[image: Bar 2]

We've left the 5kg weight where it is so $d_{5} = d'_{5}$, but because the 25kg and 10kg weights have been moved $d_{25} \ne d'_{25}$ and $d_{10} \ne d'_{10}$. That means when we do the sums to work out $T_{left}$ and $T_{right}$ there is no guarantee they will be equal. In general they won't, and the bar won't balance. The condition for the bar to still balance at the same point is:

$$ 25gd_{25} + 10gd_{10} = 25gd'_{25} + 10gd'_{10} $$

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends upon the exact dimensions of the plates.

For example, if the thickness of the plates varied in proportion to mass, and the outer diameter was constant, the order wouldn't effect the center of mass. The three masses would be equivalent to the same cylinder regardless of order.

But since in practice the outer diameter does increase with the mass, the order does matter and the center of mass would shift toward the end with the 25 kg being further out.